# The principal states.amazonaws.com is not authorized to assume the provided role with a condition on aws:sourceArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

The state machine execution fails with the following error:

```
The principal states.amazonaws.com is not authorized to assume the provided role. (role: arn:aws:iam::[masked]:role/my-state-machine-role)
```

However, the role's trust policy clearly allows the `states.amazonaws.com` principal:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:states:<regionName>:<AccountId>:stateMachine:<stateMachineNamePrefix>*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

where `<regionName>`, `<accountId>`, and `<stateMachineNamePrefix>` are placeholders for the actual values.

Implementation according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-create-iam-role.html#prevent-cross-service-confused-deputy

---

Everything works just fine if the condition is removed from the trust policy.

**EDIT**: I've contacted AWS Support and they confirmed it's a bug.

Comment: What happens if your remove `<stateMachineNamePrefix>`?

Comment: Then it works correctly.